# How to compile public es6 sources by Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a JavaScript source file in folder public/assets/js/foo.js, it uses es6 syntax, the app works on debug mode, but when I try to build a production package, it failed because of es6 syntax error.
My question is how could I compile public es6 JavaScript source by ember-cli, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is in `/public` I assume you have a `<script>` tag to import it?

You can transpile the files in `/public`, but a better way to go would be to place your file under `/app`, probably `/app/utils` and then `import` it like that:

```
import '/my-app/utils/my-file.js';
```

You can `import` the file for example in your `app.js`. This will include the file in your main build pipeline so it will get transpired and injected into your main `my-app.js` file.

---

The other way is to manually transpile it with your broccoli build pipeline. Check out [broccoli-babel-transpiler](https://github.com/babel/broccoli-babel-transpiler).

Comment: My public JavaScript is only for another page, is not part of The EmberJS App. I just want use ember-cli to compile the public es6 source file to standard JavaScript, thanks for reply.

Comment: Well then the `broccoli-babel-transpiler` with `broccoli-funnel` is exactly what you need.